# Tutorials about javaagents

Tags: java, javaagents

I'd like to learn something about javaagents, but researching is not easy. Most of result refers to `JADE`. I know java agent can mean two things:

1. An agent programmed in Java being an incarnation of the agent
   concept of distributed systems.
2. A low-level software component to augment the working of a JVM, such
   as profilers, code-coverage tools, etc

I've found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468297/java-agent-what-is-it), but unfortunately it also refers to version 1.

Do you know any articles, tutorials for beginners, sample project about javaagent in version 2? 
I've found one [here,](http://dhruba.name/2010/02/07/creation-dynamic-loading-and-instrumentation-with-javaagents/) but I'm looking for more.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277219/starting-a-java-agent-after-program-start also has some useful links

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The second case talks about [Java Instrumentation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html) - this link points to a Javadoc which is rather descriptive.

And here, is the full instruction and an [example of how to create java instrumentation agent](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/instrumentation.shtml).

The main concept is to:

1. Implement a static `premain` (as an analogy to `main`) method, like this:

   ```
   import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

   class Example {
       public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a manifest file (say, `manifest.txt`) marking this class for pre-main execution. Its contents are:

   ```
   Premain-Class: Example
   ```
3. Compile the class and package this class into a `JAR` archive:

   ```
   javac Example.java
   jar cmf manifest.txt yourAwesomeAgent.jar *.class
   ```
4. Execute your JVM with `-javaagent` parameter, like this:

   ```
   java -javaagent:yourAwesomeAgent.jar -jar yourApp.jar
   ```

Comment: It is important that the `-javaagent` parameter goes before the `-jar` parameter.

Comment: I had to add an additional entry to my manifest to get it to work with using Javassist. You can see in my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423319/how-do-you-analyze-fatal-javaagent-errors

Comment: I recently followed these steps to build an agent.  I kept running into problems creating the jar, until I found out that the command should have listed the target .jar file first and the manifest file after.

Comment: You may also need to provide an empty `main` method in the `Example` class, or an error may be thrown complaining about the lack of the main method.

Comment: remember to finish the manifest.txt whit a blank line

Answer (score 6):

Few useful resources for the javaagent as described in point #2.

- [How-to guide to writing a javaagent](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-inspect-classes-in-your-jvm/)
- [Taming Javaagents - presentation at BCN JUG
  2015](https://speakerdeck.com/shelajev/taming-javaagents-bcn-jug-2015)
- [API documentation for
  java.lang.instrument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html)