# jdb using -javaagent option

Tags: java, jdb

I am  using an opensource tool called dimmunix to catch the deadlock sequence and in particular interested in creating a sequence of interleaving to create deadlock manually using jdb.If i am  using java with dimmunix with -java agent option it is perfectly working fine.But whenever i am trying to run it with  jdb -J-javaagent option it is throwing an exception i have a strong feeling that it is not relation to my application/tool,

Exception is

```
Exception in thread "launched target monitor" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:181)
    at com.sun.tools.jdi.AbstractLauncher$Helper$1.run(AbstractLauncher.java:235)
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Copy and paste you commands and error message including stack trace from the exception instead of rephrasing it

Comment: jdb -classpath ./dimmunix-java/test -J-Xbootclasspath/p:./dimmunix-java/src/Dimmunix/bin:./asm-3.2/lib/asm-3.2.jar -J-javaagent:./dimmunix-java/src/DimmunixInstrumentation/DimmunixAgent.jar dimmunixTests.Test                    Initializing jdb ...
> run
run dimmunixTests.Test
Exception in thread "launched target monitor" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
 at java.lang.UNIXProcess.waitFor(UNIXProcess.java:181)
 at com.sun.tools.jdi.AbstractLauncher$Helper$1.run(AbstractLauncher.java:235)
Set uncaught java.lang.Throwable
Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable
>

Comment: @MiserableVariable please reply if you have any idea...

Comment: I am afraid I don't. There is no `-J` flag for `jdb` so I am pretty sure you are doing that wrong, but I can relate that to the error message

Comment: @MiserableVariable http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html documentation by oracle it is given that we can use -J  option ...is it correct?

Comment: You are correct, I had a blackout because on command line did not list that (but it does accept it). But what is `java.lang.UnixProcess`? Is that a class from `JDK`?

Comment: @MiserableVariable even i m unable  to find out why it is coming?

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the right arguments?  -J-javaagent does not seem correct.  See [Tutorials about javaagents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898566/tutorials-about-javaagents)

Comment: I am actually modifying the same command i am using with java jdb -classpath ./dimmunix-java/test -J-Xbootclasspath/p:./dimmunix-java/src/Dimmunix/bin:./asm-3.2/lib/asm-3.2.jar -J-javaagent:./dimmunix-java/src/DimmunixInstrumentation/DimmunixAgent.jar dimmunixTests.Test