# Try to use Agent in Webapplication for bytecode Manupulation

Tags: java, web-applications, javassist, bytecode-manipulation, javaagents

I'm not that good in Java but I have my webApplication running on a Wildfly.
I have 3 threads who just call a function that insert logs in in and the function saves the logs to a Database and after that every thread sends a time how long did it takes to do this.
They send the data to another programm I wrote what has 3 threads to call one of the 3 server threads.

So now I try to do some ByteCode Manipulation every thread on the server saves the datetime call the log function waits 1 second and returns then the time they needed.

1 Thread write something in an logfile before or after they waitet 1 second.
But this part where they wait a second and call the log function I want that to inject to every 3 threads with Bytecode manipulation.

```
public class MyTransformer implements ClassFileTransformer {


@Override
public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class redefiningClass, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] bytes) throws IllegalClassFormatException {

    return transformClass(redefiningClass, bytes);
}

private byte[] transformClass(Class classToTransform, byte[] b) {
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass cl = null;
    try {
        cl = pool.get("de.soptim.ws.MyApplication");
    } catch (javassist.NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {

        assert cl != null;
        CtMethod[] methods = cl.getMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            if (methods[i].isEmpty() == false) {
                changeMethod(methods[i]);
            }
        }
        b = cl.toBytecode();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (cl != null) {
            cl.detach();
        }
    }
    return b;
}

private void changeMethod(CtMethod method) throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {

    if (method.hasAnnotation(Loggable.class)) {
        method.insertBefore("threadLogger.info(\"ADDED THIS FROM BYTECODE !!!\");");
        method.insertAfter("threadLogger.info(\"ADDED THIS FROM BYTECODE !!!\");");
    }
}}
```

Thats my transformer class it should increase the Code my Methods need it checks what Method has an @Loggable annotation an then adds the code into it("at the moment it's just some log statments for checking if it works")

My biggest problem is now that I don't know how to call my agent ... I googled hwo to call an agent at runtime with agentmain() but I think I dind't really understood how it works.

Agent Class

```
public class LogAgent  {

public static void agentmain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {
    System.out.println("Starting the agent");
    inst.addTransformer(new MyTransformer());
}}
```

Hope you understand My problem :) I and if you answere pleas try to stay noob friendly :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't call your agent explicitly, you should specify additional argument to your JVM :

`java -javaagent:jarpath[=options]`

where `jarpath` is a path to jar containing your agent. JVM will invoke `premain` method before `main` method of java program.

And `transform` method will be called before classloading by JVM (you don't call it explicitly).

Last remark : you should implement `premain` method, not `agentmain`.
`agentmain` is used during attaching to running vm, while `premain` is used when you start JVM with `-javaagent` method.

And make sure that your jar have valid manifest, as described : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html

I haven't using javaassit so I cannot say that your code is valid, but instrumenting webapp server like Wildfly is much harder than normal java app (mostly due to classloaders visibility and hierarchy).

See also :

http://www.tomsquest.com/blog/2014/01/intro-java-agent-and-bytecode-manipulation/
[Tutorials about javaagents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898566/tutorials-about-javaagents)

Comment: Oke first thanks for your answere :D but "java -javaagent:jarpath[=options]"  I just know this as command for CMD and I can't use this o: or can I add it somwhere else ?

Comment: And I used premain because I tried to change the code while it's running but that didn't worked too ...

Comment: Modify server start script and and this to JVM args. I done that this way and it works fine.