# How to solve CompletionFailure when using EclipseLink Modelgen processor and Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring-security, eclipselink

I am trying to use Spring Security in a project where I use eclipselink as the modelgen processor to generate the static meta model. 
When I try to do this I get strange compilation errors like:

```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource not found
```

even though I do not use LDAP. If I add the jars I get other errors like missing sl4j, missing openid, etc etc.
If I exchange the used modelgen processor with the hibernate implementation everything compiles without problems.

I found a minimal project to reproduce the problem:

MyEnity.java

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    private String name;
    private Long id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'com.demo'
version = 'alpha'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

repositories {
    maven { url "http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" }
    maven { url "http://download.eclipse.org/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo/" }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor:2.6.0'//latest stable @06.07.2015


    compile "org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.6.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.6.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-web:4.1.6.RELEASE"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.6.RELEASE"
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.1.6.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:4.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:4.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:4.0.2.RELEASE'

    providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:7.0@jar'
}
```

As soon as I remove

a) the @Entity from MyEntity

or

b)  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter from Security Config

or

c) use `compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:4.3.10.Final'`
instead of `compile 'org.eclipse.persistence:org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor:2.6.0'`

everything compiles without problems.

So why does the use of the eclipselink modelgen processor cause compilation errors?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution to that? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Maciej I worked around the problem by using the hibernate-jpamodelgen as mentioned in my original question. So far I had no problems using the metamodel generated by hibernate with Ecpliselink as the persistence provider.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `CanonicalModelProcessor` of EclipseLink modelgen, even using version 2.7.4. It works as a [Java Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11898653/12890) getting all classes on the classpath to process. At some point it hits a Spring Security class (like `HttpSecurity` in my case) which has a indirect dependency on a library not found on the classpath (typically from an inner class or a factory return type as Spring is designed fine, `OpenIDLoginConfigurer` returned by `HttpSecurity.openidLogin()` referencing `OpenIDAttribute` etc. in my case) - at that point the whole agent crashes instead of skipping the type.

The problem is not specific to Spring or Spring Security but any project using optional dependencies missing on the classpath!

Surprisingly it seems to work using OpenJDK 11 but not using OpenJDK 8. From my point the `CanonicalModelProcessor` is buggy. At the end I added the generated meta model to our project repo and dropped modelgen for now.

UPDATE: I know this is no real answer (if you cannot move to OpenJDK 11) but at least I wanted to make clear it is a bug of EclipseLink without a workaround (as far as I know).