# Problem Integrating Java EE 7, Spring Security and EclipseLink

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, spring-security, eclipselink

fellow developers. Hope you are having a great day today.

I am facing a problem which I do not know how to solve, been at it for a while now. I am trying to integrate Java EE 7, Spring Security and EclipseLink to do form base authentication for an application that is to be hosted on a Payara Server.

I am going to list the artifacts corresponding to my current implementation:

> **pom.xml**

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-bom</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>                
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Note: as you can see in the pom.xml file, I had to comment out the modelgen processor of EclipseLink as the project won't compile with it. So I have to un-comment it whenever I am doing reverse engineering to generate the entities from my database, and comment it again for building and running the application. It seems that the CanonicalModelProcessor (EclipseLink's modelgen that is used to generate type-safe JPAQueries) has problems if Spring Security is also present in the project. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31832360/how-to-solve-completionfailure-when-using-eclipselink-modelgen-processor-and-spr) on StackOverflow that proves this point as another user had the same problem as I.

> **WebSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.myapp.testapp.security")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/Views/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/Views/accesodenegado.xhtml");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

> **CustomAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Inject
    private UsuarioFacade usuarioFacade; 

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        System.out.println(password);

        boolean authenticationIsSuccessful = WsAutenticacion.login(username, password);

        if (authenticationIsSuccessful) {
            System.out.println("Authentication successful");

            Usuario usuario = usuarioFacade.obtenerUsuario(username);

            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, usuario.authorities);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

> **UsuarioFacade.java**

```
@Stateless
public class UsuarioFacade extends AbstractFacade<Usuario> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.myapp.testapp_war_1.0PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public UsuarioFacade() {
        super(Usuario.class);
    }

    public Usuario obtenerUsuario(String username) {
        String qlString = "SELECT u FROM Usuario u JOIN u.perfil p WHERE u.username = :username";
        Usuario usuario = (Usuario) getEntityManager().createQuery(qlString).setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult();

        return usuario;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am using a custom AuthenticationProvider class as, per requirements, the authentication must be performed by sending the username and password to a SOAP service which returns true or false depending on whether the principal and credentials exist in Active Directory, which the webservice queries whenever you use this service. As the authorities are not stored in Active Directory, I need to query a database which has them for a specific user --- I am using EclipseLink for this step.

The problem I am having is that I am trying to inject the Facade into the custom AuthorizationProvider, and the application crashes with the following error:

```
Severe:   Exception during cleanup after start failed
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been started
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:867)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:5735)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5552)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2057)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1703)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:501)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Severe:   ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customAuthenticationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usuarioFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.testapp.facade.UsuarioFacade' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:522)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2057)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1703)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:501)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:220)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:487)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:466)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customAuthenticationProvider'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usuarioFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.testapp.facade.UsuarioFacade' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4965)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5534)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuthenticationProvider': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'usuarioFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.testapp.facade.UsuarioFacade' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.myapp.testapp.facade.UsuarioFacade' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1654)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593)
    ... 80 more
```

I know that if I remove the injected stateless EJB, the application runs smoothly, but then I would have no way of loading the authorities for a specific user. Can any of you guys teach me how to make use of EclipseLink to load the authorities of the user by injecting it into my custom AuthenticationProvider, or if there is another way that I could load these authorities?

Thank you in advance for any and all replies guys.

Comment: Probably a bad idea to try to integrate EclipseLink and Spring Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are mixing spring bean annotations and CDI/EJB annotations. The error basically says that there is no bean of type UsuarioFacade available to inject into the CustomAuthenticationProvider. Are you sure UsuarioFacade is picked up as a Bean/EJB?

Since it is Spring doing the injecting, it needs to pickup the EJB annotation @Stateless. Is this stateless session bean in the package that Spring component scans?

I haven't been able to find an example of getting spring to work with this annotation, are you sure Spring picks it up? 
What if your stateless bean extends `AbstractStatelessSessionBean`? 
Or another try, what if it is annotated with the spring `@Singleton` annotation?