# How to uniq identify a Function in Java 8

Tags: java, function, equals, hashcode

I am asking whether I can take a function as key for a map.

Normally, a key object for a map should have `hashcode` and `equal` methods. However,  Java `Function` is a method object, and it does not have these two methods.

```
Function<String, String> quote1 = s -> "'" + s + "'";
Function<String, String> quote2 = s -> "'" + s + "'";
System.out.println(quote1.equals(quote2));  //false
```

so is it possible?  If possible, any sample?  I did not get this case by google.

If not, is there any other way to identify time-consuming `Function` execution result? 
Thanks

Comment: `hashcode` and `equal` are implemented by Object. So it is possible to use a `Function` as a key, however the default implementation of those methods is based on the reference of the object. So two `Function` objects that are the same but have different references will appear to be different keys.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: @Andreas So is there some way to identify time-consuming `function` execution result?

Comment: Measure it. Remember, execution time of a function often depends heavily on the function input, so without a particular input, you can't measure anything, and the result may not apply to any other input.

Answer (score 0):

Both - `quote1` and `quote2` - are baked by some Java class created by compiler.

Here is another discussion how to get access to bytecode

[How to get bytecode as byte array from Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35071016/how-to-get-bytecode-as-byte-array-from-class)

Though, it is not recommended.

What is your goal behind this question?

Comment: The `quote` function represents some calculation, e.g. DB retrieval, and I want to cache the result by the function. The problem for me is that the `function` calculation depends on environment variables, instead of its parameters. Maybe i have to refact the design

Comment: Environment variables cannot be changed once application is started (i.e. changes will not be visible to app) so these do not affect result caching.

Comment: Still not clear why do you need to compare two functions

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use full-blown classes with the methods `hashCode` and `equals` implemented:

```
public class StringStringFunction implements Function<String, String> {
    static String id = "'+s+'";

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof StringStringFunction;
    }

    @Override
    public String apply(String s) {
        return  "'" + s + "'";
    }
}
```

then we can write:

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
    Function<String, String> quote1 = new StringStringFunction();
    Function<String, String> quote2 = new StringStringFunction();
    System.out.println(quote1.equals(quote2));  //true
}
```

Comment: So how to write the Constructor with a `Function` parameter? e.g.,  `public StringStringFunction(Function<String, String> fun)`?  In this case, we still have problem for field memers (i.e., assigning `id` value)?

Comment: why do you want  to write a constructor with a Function parameter? this has no sense.

Comment: Thanks. I think I have got the point. The `function` itself can not have `equal` and `hashcode` methods. So the `StringFunction` uses an indirect way.l